# Using Spring Data JPA after performing save operation not able to get Parent record values

Tags: spring, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

Below are the mapping table pojo.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
public class User implements Serializable{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "user_id", nullable = false, updatable = false)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "first_name")
    private String firstName;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user")
    private  Collection<Company>  companyList;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }
    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }
    public Collection<Company> getCompanyList() {
        return companyList;
    }
    public void setCompanyList(Collection<Company> companyList) {
        this.companyList = companyList;
    }
}
```

and

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "company")
public class Company {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "company_id", nullable = false, updatable = false)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "company_name")
    private String companyName;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="user_id")
    private User user;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getCompanyName() {
        return companyName;
    }
    public void setCompanyName(String companyName) {
        this.companyName = companyName;
    }
    public User getUser() {
        return user;
    }
    public void setUser(User user) {
        this.user = user;
    }
```

}

Below code is will be stored data into company table.

```
        User user = new User();
        Company saveCompany = new Company();
        **user.setId(1L);**
        saveCompany.setUser(user);
        saveCompany.setCompanyName("test company18");

        **companyRepository.save(saveCompany);**
```

But, when i call below code, the value of firstName is displayed null.

```
        company = companyRepository.findCompanyByName("test company18");
        System.out.println("After new company test company:------" + company.getCompanyName());
        System.out.println("After new company test User Id:------" + company.getUser().getId());
        System.out.println("After new company test User FirstName:------" + **company.getUser().getFirstName()**);
```

what will be the changes required to get FirstName value instead of null.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: A BIDIRECTIONAL relation should have "mappedBy" specified on one of the sides ... otherwise it is 2 UNIDIRECTIONAL relations!

Comment: sorry, i forget to mention mappedBy. I have updated User class. Please refer the same.

Comment: Where is the FirstName supposed to come from? It never gets set.

Comment: FirstName get-set come from User class. please see updated one.